# How to hide the constness of a in a pointer wrapper. const-erasure?

Tags: c++

Let's say we have an interface that provides some const and non-const methods and we have a class that takes an instance of this interface and calls methods on it:

```
struct IService{
    virtual void doConstThing() const = 0;
    virtual void doNonconstThing() = 0;
};

struct A{
    IService* svc;
    void f() {
        svc->doConstThing(); // always do the const thing
        if constexpr (!std::is_const_v<IService>) { // maybe do the non-const thing
            svc->doNonconstThing();
        }
    }
};
```

This doesn't work because `svc` is always non-const; its part of `A` definition.

One fix is to pull the `IService` type up into a template argument:

```
template <typename SvcPtr>
struct A{
    SvcPtr svc;
    void f() {
        svc->doConstThing(); // always do the const thing
        if constexpr (!std::is_const_v<std::remove_pointer<SvcPtr>>) { // maybe do the non-const thing
            svc->doNonconstThing();
        }
    }
};
```

Above, we capture whether `ptr` is const or non-const. The `if constexpr` now works, but we've complicated `A` significatnly. In the real-world code, `A` has many more member functions. Also my team may not be so confident with template code. Review might be difficult for them.

So, I'd like to eliminate the template argument from `A` and isolate it in to the `svc` pointer. I'd like to "wrap away" the constness of `ptr` so the definition of `A` does not change:

```
template <typename T> // how?
struct MaybeConstPtr{ 
    constexpr bool is_const();
    auto operator->();
};

struct A{
    MaybeConstPtr<IService> svc;
    A(const IService* constptr) : svc(constptr) {};
    A(IService* nonconstptr) : svc(nonconstptr){}
    void f() {
        svc->doConstThing(); // always do the const thing
        if constexpr (svc.is_const()) { // maybe do the non-const thing
            svc->doNonconstThing();
        }
    }
};
```

Overloading the `A` constructor to initialize `svc` with either a const or non-const pointer, then ask `svc` at compile-time whether we should do non-const stuff.

Any ideas for achieving something like this? Is there something in the standard I've missed?

Comment: _"Also my team may not be so confident with template code. Review might be difficult for them."_ sounds like your team needs some proper training. There is nothing difficult with your code. It's quite expressive IMHO. An alternative solution to yours could be to have separate overloads of the method for const and non-const types. (the non-const can of course use the const): separation of responsibilities.

Comment: `std::variant<T*, const T*>` might do the job.

Comment: `if constexpr (svc.is_const())`. it is not `constexpr`, as it depends of which constructor has been called.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yeah, but adding a templatle argument to an old class with many member functions is an ugly refactor.

Comment: @Jarod42 Hmm, that might work. Will try sketching it out to see how bad the diff looks. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of your code, combined with Jarod42's suggestion of `std::variant`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>

using std::cout;
using std::decay_t;
using std::is_same_v;
using std::variant;
using std::visit;

template<class> inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

namespace {

struct IService {
    virtual ~IService() = default;
    virtual void doConstThing() const = 0;
    virtual void doNonconstThing() = 0;
};

struct MyService : IService {
    void doConstThing() const override {
        cout << "MyService doConstThing\n";
    }
    void doNonconstThing() override {
        cout << "MyService doNonconstThing\n";
    }
};

struct A {
    variant<IService*, IService const*> svc;

    A(const IService* constptr) : svc(constptr) {}
    A(IService* nonconstptr) : svc(nonconstptr) {}

    void f() {
        visit([](auto&& arg) {
            using T = decay_t<decltype(arg)>;

            if constexpr (is_same_v<T, IService const*>) {
                cout << "const IService\n";
                arg->doConstThing(); // Always.
            } else if constexpr (is_same_v<T, IService*>) {
                cout << "mut IService\n";
                arg->doConstThing(); // Always.
                arg->doNonconstThing(); // Only if mutable.
            } else {
                static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "non-exhaustive visitor!");
            }
        }, svc);
    }
};

} // anon

int main() {
    MyService service;
    MyService const* p = &service;
    cout << "Let's try a mutable service:\n";
    A a(&service);
    a.f();

    cout << "--------------------------\n";
    cout << "Let's try a const service:\n";
    A aa(p);
    aa.f();
}
```

Comment: That's painful, but not as bad as I thought it'd be. Thanks! Which is worse, I wonder, reviewing a template refactor on the legacy class or getting through `std::variant`s interface? :-D

Comment: `overloaded` (from [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) example) might be a good alternative to the `if constexpr`. or a dedicated wrapper for the `Visitor`.